# Trailing Whitespaces Appended to Fixed-Length Property in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

I'm facing an issue in my **.NET 8** application where trailing whitespaces are being appended to a fixed-length property (**UserName**) when stored in the database. I am using Database provider - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.
I am using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore for identity store with custom classes inheriting from identity classes. I've configured the property as follows:

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entity)
    {
        entity.Property(u => u.UserName)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsRequired();
```

However, during the seeding process, when I create a new User object with UserName = "username", it's stored in the database as:
"username                                          (*whitespaces until 50 chars*)" -> note that sequence has 50 chars, it trails whitespaces after username until it gets to 50 chars (it cannot be seen exactly in the string here due to SO's formatting)

**User Class:**

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
// ... UserName inherited from IdentityUser ...
```

**User Configuration:**

```
public class UserConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entity)
    {
    entity.Property(u => u.UserName)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .IsRequired();

    // ... other configurations ...
}
}
```

**Seeding Logic:**

```
var admin = new User
{
Id = 1,
FirstName = "John",
LastName = "Doe",
UserName = "username", // No trailing whitespaces here
Email = "username@yahoo.com",
// ... other properties ...
};
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasData(users);
```

**Context Class:**

```
public class LibraryContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Generated Create User Table Script:

```
USE [LibApp]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedByUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedByUserId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [CardCode] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Currency] [char](3) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ImagePath] [char](255) NULL,
    [IsCardActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LastLoginDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Notes] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [RoleId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TotalFee] [decimal](10, 2) NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentId] [nvarchar](13) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_User] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] ADD  DEFAULT (N'') FOR [DocumentId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Role_RoleId] FOREIGN KEY([RoleId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Role] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_Role_RoleId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_User_CreatedByUserId] FOREIGN KEY([CreatedByUserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_User_CreatedByUserId]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_User_User_ModifiedByUserId] FOREIGN KEY([ModifiedByUserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_User_User_ModifiedByUserId]
GO
```

I reckon that it has to do something with custom configuration & identity configuration.
Note that I have tried removing custom UserName property configuration and leaving it to identity to configure it by itself, but the issue persists.
Why are trailing whitespaces being appended to the UserName property even though it's configured with .HasMaxLength(50)?
How can I ensure that the UserName property is stored without any trailing whitespaces?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It is known behaviour of `char(n)` columns. Use `varchar(n)` instead.

Comment: EF Core maps strings to nvarchar already, so this does not fix the issue.

Comment: So, your columns in database are `varchar`? Show your table using SQL DDL statement. Also specify EF Core version Database provider.

Comment: Database provider - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
My columns are nvarchar, although I have tried setting them explicitly to varchar but the issue prevails. I will generate script in the answer

Comment: Can you create idempotent script and analyse what happened? [Idempotent SQL Scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#idempotent-sql-scripts)

Comment: I can, but that one has over 3k lines, or do you want the ones related just to User table?

Comment: Something is explicitly configuring the type because the default mapping for strings in EF/SQL Server is `nvarchar`, not `varchar`. The behaviour with padding seems to think it is dealing with a `char(50)`. You might need to post the complete UserConfiguration class as there might be something conflicting tucked away in there. Also check that you don't have any configuration code referencing User in OnModelCreating.

Comment: I have idea that data was inserted when tables had `char(n)` column, then tables were altered. Analyse scripts by yourself.

Comment: Both of you are right. I have investigated the generated idempotent script, and at one point, before the data is inserted the column is altered as char(50), and after that one the data is inserted, so after that, none of the things in migrations I did managed to "correct" that via migrations. The only thing was executing raw sql:
UPDATE [LibApp].[dbo].[User]
SET UserName = LTRIM(RTRIM(UserName)),
Email = LTRIM(RTRIM(Email));
and after duing that one manually the behavior is as expected. So now I am considering to put that sql into the next migration. But you have helped me track the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to creating table with char(50) in one of the migrations, which has knows issues with whitespaces, then adding data after that.